# SQL Query - Dynamic Columns will not sort according to SO

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have created a pivot query that I want the cross applied dynamic 'columns' to sort in a specific way, and they will not.

This is how the dynamic 'columns' are being returned:
[Cd - Conc] [Cd - RL] [Cd - Q] [Cd - MDL]

This is how I want them to return:
[Cd - Conc] [Cd - Q] [Cd - MDL] [Cd - RL]

I have limited my query to one analyte "Cd" while I try to get the sort order as described above, but the total number of analytes is not known necessarily.  I want them to order by analyte by conc, q, mdl, rl so this would look like [Cd - Conc] [Cd - Q] [Cd - MDL] [Cd - RL] [Se - Conc] [Se - Q] [Se - MDL] [Se - RL] [Zr - Conc] [Zr - Q] [Zr - MDL] [Zr - RL] etc

This is my code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--
-- This variable holds the field values that will pivot to become column headers.
--
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max);
--
-- This variable holds the dynamic pivot query.
--
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);

--
-- First, we need to get the dynamic 'columns'. We do this by replicating
-- the FROM and WHERE clause that will show up in the pivot query. In the
-- SELECT, we only need to create the dynamic 'columns'. We must replicate
-- the FROM and WHERE clause or we'll end up with all rows from AN.[abbreviation].
--
-- This query is inside the STUFF function, which can build a string without
-- resorting to looping constructs.
--
-- The QUOTENAME function wraps a string in brackets, e.g. my_col becomes [my_col].
--
-- The end result of this is we get a comma-separated string of the form:
-- [Ag],[As], ...
--
SELECT  @cols = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            ',' + QUOTENAME(AN.[abbreviation] + col)
        FROM                
                                [project]       P
        INNER JOIN  [monitoring_event_type]     MET                 ON P.[id] = MET.[project_id] 
        INNER JOIN  [monitoring_event]          ME                  ON MET.[id] = ME.[event_type_id] 
        INNER JOIN  [sample]                    S                   ON ME.[id] = S.[event_id] 
        INNER JOIN  [location]                  L                   ON L.[id] = S.[location_id]
        INNER JOIN  [analysis]                  A                   ON A.[sample_id] = S.[id] 
        INNER JOIN  [result]                    R                   ON R.[analysis_id] = A.[id] 
        INNER JOIN  [result_qualifier]          RQ                  ON RQ.[id] = R.[id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [result_validation]         RV                  ON RV.[id] = R.[id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [sample_type]               ST                  ON ST.[id] = R.[sample_type_id] 
        INNER JOIN  [analyte]                   AN                  ON AN.[id] = R.[analyte_id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [parameter_type]            PT                  ON PT.[id] = AN.[parameter_type_id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [unit]                      U                   ON U.[id] = R.[unit_id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [analyte_fraction]          ANF                 ON ANF.[id] = R.[analyte_fraction_id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [organization]              O1                  ON O1.[id] = S.[sampler_id]
        LEFT JOIN   [organization]              O2                  ON O2.[id] = A.[lab_id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [analysis_method]           AM                  ON AM.[id] = A.[analysis_method_id]


        CROSS APPLY
        (       

            SELECT ' - Conc',1                  UNION ALL
            SELECT ' - Q',2                     UNION ALL
            SELECT ' - MDL' ,3                  UNION ALL
            SELECT ' - RL', 4                       --Do not use UNION ALL on the last line

        ) AS c (col,so)


        WHERE
                    P.id = 6 
            AND     S.sample_source = 'Field' 
                        AND     AN.abbreviation in('Cd')
            --          AND     AN.abbreviation in('Ba', 'Cd','Se','Zr')


--Adding FOR XML PATH to the end of a query allows you to output the results of the query as XML elements, with the element name contained in the PATH argument.
        FOR XML PATH,TYPE
        ).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
); -- END of STUFF function

--
-- Now we build the dynamic query using @cols variable where needed.
--
SET @query = '
SELECT
    pvt.[EventName]
    ,pvt.[Location]
    ,pvt.[FieldSampleID]
    ,pvt.[DateCollected]
    ,'+ @cols +'

FROM
(
    SELECT
        ME.event_name                                               AS [EventName]
        ,O2.organization_name                                       AS [LAB]
        ,A.sdg                                                      AS [SDG]
        ,L.name_or_geocode                                          AS [Location]
        ,ST.type                                                    AS [SampleType]
        ,A.lab_sample_ident                                         AS [LabSampleID]
        ,S.sample_ident                                             AS [FieldSampleID]
        ,CAST(S.monitoring_date as Date)                            AS [DateCollected]

        --
        -- The following two fields represent the pivot parameters
        --
        ,col = AN.[abbreviation] + col
        ,val                                                    


    FROM            [project]                   P
        INNER JOIN  [monitoring_event_type]     MET                 ON P.[id] = MET.[project_id] 
        INNER JOIN  [monitoring_event]          ME                  ON MET.[id] = ME.[event_type_id] 
        INNER JOIN  [sample]                    S                   ON ME.[id] = S.[event_id] 
        INNER JOIN  [location]                  L                   ON L.[id] = S.[location_id] 
        INNER JOIN  [analysis]                  A                   ON A.[sample_id] = S.[id]
        INNER JOIN  [result]                    R                   ON R.[analysis_id] = A.[id] 
        INNER JOIN  [result_qualifier]          RQ                  ON RQ.[id] = R.[id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [result_validation]         RV                  ON RV.[id] = R.[id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [sample_type]               ST                  ON ST.[id] = R.[sample_type_id] 
        INNER JOIN  [analyte]                   AN                  ON AN.[id] = R.[analyte_id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [parameter_type]            PT                  ON PT.[id] = AN.[parameter_type_id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [unit]                      U                   ON U.[id] = R.[unit_id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [analyte_fraction]          ANF                 ON ANF.[id] = R.[analyte_fraction_id]
        LEFT JOIN   [organization]              O1                  ON O1.[id] = S.[sampler_id]
        LEFT JOIN   [organization]              O2                  ON O2.[id] = A.[lab_id] 
        LEFT JOIN   [analysis_method]           AM                  ON AM.[id] = A.[analysis_method_id]

        CROSS APPLY
                (
            SELECT '' - Conc'',CAST(R.[VALUE] AS varchar(20)) UNION ALL
            SELECT '' - Q'',CAST(RQ.[qualifiers] AS varchar(20)) UNION ALL
            SELECT '' - MDL'',CAST(RQ.[MDL] AS varchar(20)) UNION ALL
            SELECT '' - RL'',CAST(RQ.[RL] AS varchar(20)) --Do not use UNION ALL on the last line

        ) AS c (col,val)


    WHERE
                    P.id = 6 
            AND     S.sample_source = ''Field'' 
            AND     AN.abbreviation in(''Cd'')
            --AND       AN.abbreviation in(''Ba'', ''Cd'',''Se'',''Zr'')
        ) AS t


PIVOT
(
    Max(t.[val])
    FOR col IN ('+ @cols +')
)AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.[EventName], pvt.[Location];
';
--
-- Execute the sql string contained in @query.
--
--Print @query
EXECUTE(@query);    
--Select (@query);
```

Comment: Are you expecting the `so` column to just magically sort the columns without being used in an ORDER BY for some reason?   For that matter, why do you care what order the columns are returned in?

Comment: I am trying to sort the dynamic columns (headers) to the right of the EventName, Location, FieldSampleID, DateCollected that are being sorted properly, not the data going down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SO` column in an ORDER BY in the query that creates `@cols`.

Comment: I am unclear how to do this. If I add ORDER BY @cols I get an error that says "The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name."

Comment: @D.STKO try `ORDER BY SO`

Comment: I get the error - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: Can you remove the "DISTINCT"?

Comment: I get the error: The column 'Cd 01 - Conc' was specified multiple times for 'pvt'.

Comment: I would have to see your full current query to comment further.   Please add it to your question, instead of a comment to my answer.